# Time zone conversion join to data table sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, timezone, subquery

I have written some code that allows me to convert from UTC time to a local time, but the time I am passing in is a dummy value and so is the time zone. I'd like this to be able to work with actual data, but I am not sure how to combine. Possibly a sub-query?

Here is my query for time zone conversion:

```
Select From_Tz(Cast(To_Timestamp('17-FEB-14 04.00.00.000000000 PM',
'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM') As Timestamp), 'UTC')
 At Time Zone 'America/New_York' As "Local Time"
 FROM DUAL;
```

In place of the '17-FEB-14 04.00.00.000000000 PM' and 'America/New_York', I would like to pass in values returned from the following query:

```
Select s.Max(Date), time.Local_Time_Zone from Sales s
join on s.customer_ID = time.customer_ID
where s.customer_ID = 122;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one record in the table for that ID, which seems likely, then you don't need the `max()` or a subquery, you can just select directly from that table, like:

```
select from_tz(cast(date_field as timestamp), 'UTC')
  at time zone customer_time_zone as "Local Time"
from customer_table;
```

I'm also assuming your 'date' field is actually a `DATE`, not already a `TIMEZONE`, but that's not entirely clear.

With formatting for display:

```
select to_char(from_tz(cast(date_field as timestamp), 'UTC')
  at time zone customer_time_zone, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as "Local Time"
from customer_table;

LOCAL TIME
-------------------
2014-02-16 19:00:00
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe1b2c/2)

---

Based on your updated question, the principal is the same, you just have two tables to join:

```
select to_char(from_tz(cast(max(s.date_field) as timestamp), 'UTC')
  at time zone t.local_time_zone, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as "Local Time"
from sales s
join time t on t.customer_id = s.customer_id
group by s.customer_id, t.local_time_zone;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbfe4/4).

Comment: Sorry, I tried to over-simplify the statement. Time zone and date are from two different tables and are joined together. I have modified my original post to clarify.

Comment: @user2242044 - same idea; updated the answer to use your join.